# What are the best practices to make a good REST API request cache key?

Tags: rest, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, memcached, spring-cache

I am building a simple API service using Ruby on Rails. In production, I would like to integrate `Redis/Memcached` in order to cache some frequently-used endpoints with key-based caching. For example, I have a Car table with `name` and `color` fields.

My question is, what is the best way to define a cache key for a particular endpoint `(eg. /cars`) when the resource has variety of params that could come in different order? eg. `/cars?name=honda&color=white`, `/cars?color=white&name=honda`.

If I use request url as cache key I will have 2 different cache records but technically speaking, if both `name` and `color` have the same values, there should only be one cache record in Redis database.

Answer (score 1):

arrange the parameters in alphabetical order and use that as the basis for a cache key.

```
/cars?name=honda&color=white
/cars?color=white&name=honda
```

in both cases the cache key would be based on the concatenated alphabetically listed parameters

```
colorname
```

So both the above reordered urls would result in the same cache key.